# Why do my icons not appear in the main window of my PySide2 project?

Tags: python, anaconda, pyside2, qresource

I have a basic Pyside2 project with the following main.py code:

```
import sys
import resources_rc
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication

class MyApp():
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = QUiLoader().load("MyApp.ui")
        self.ui.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = MyApp()
    app.exec_()
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
.
├── main.py
├── MyApp.ui
├── Resources.qrc
├── resources_rc.py
└── icons
    ├── pqClip.png
    ├── pqSlice.png
    ├── pqThreshold.png
    ├── pqXplus.png
    ├── pqXminus.png
    ├── pqYplus.png
    ├── pqYminus.png
    ├── pqZplus.png
    ├── pqZminus.png
```

My Resources.qrc file looks like this:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource>
    <file>icons/pqClip.png</file>
    <file>icons/pqSlice.png</file>
    <file>icons/pqThreshold.png</file>
    <file>icons/pqXplus.png</file>
    <file>icons/pqXminus.png</file>
    <file>icons/pqYplus.png</file>
    <file>icons/pqYminus.png</file>
    <file>icons/pqZplus.png</file>
    <file>icons/pqZminus.png</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

MyApp.ui:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1217</width>
    <height>729</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MyApp</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="horizontalSpacing">
     <number>4</number>
    </property>
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_2">
       <property name="frameShape">
        <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
       </property>
       <property name="frameShadow">
        <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
       </property>
       <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
        <property name="leftMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="topMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="rightMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="bottomMargin">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <property name="verticalSpacing">
         <number>2</number>
        </property>
        <item row="0" column="0">
         <widget class="QWidget" name="menuWidget" native="true">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Minimum">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="menuLayout">
           <property name="spacing">
            <number>4</number>
           </property>
           <property name="leftMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="topMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="rightMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <property name="bottomMargin">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <item>
            <widget class="QWidget" name="filterBtnWidget" native="true">
             <property name="sizePolicy">
              <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
               <horstretch>0</horstretch>
               <verstretch>0</verstretch>
              </sizepolicy>
             </property>
             <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="filterBtnLayout">
              <property name="spacing">
               <number>4</number>
              </property>
              <property name="leftMargin">
               <number>0</number>
              </property>
              <property name="topMargin">
               <number>0</number>
              </property>
              <property name="rightMargin">
               <number>0</number>
              </property>
              <property name="bottomMargin">
               <number>0</number>
              </property>
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="clipBtn">
                <property name="toolTip">
                 <string>Add Clip Filter</string>
                </property>
                <property name="statusTip">
                 <string/>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string/>
                </property>
                <property name="icon">
                 <iconset resource="../Workspace/MyApp/Resources.qrc">
                  <normaloff>:/icons/pqClip.png</normaloff>:/icons/pqClip.png</iconset>
                </property>
                <property name="iconSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>24</width>
                  <height>24</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="flat">
                 <bool>true</bool>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="sliceBtn">
                <property name="toolTip">
                 <string>Add Slice Filter</string>
                </property>
                <property name="statusTip">
                 <string/>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string/>
                </property>
                <property name="icon">
                 <iconset resource="../Workspace/MyApp/Resources.qrc">
                  <normaloff>:/icons/pqSlice.png</normaloff>:/icons/pqSlice.png</iconset>
                </property>
                <property name="iconSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>24</width>
                  <height>24</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="flat">
                 <bool>true</bool>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="thresholdBtn">
                <property name="toolTip">
                 <string>Add Threshold Filter</string>
                </property>
                <property name="statusTip">
                 <string/>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string/>
                </property>
                <property name="icon">
                 <iconset resource="../Workspace/MyApp/Resources.qrc">
                  <normaloff>:/icons/pqThreshold.png</normaloff>:/icons/pqThreshold.png</iconset>
                </property>
                <property name="iconSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>24</width>
                  <height>24</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="flat">
                 <bool>true</bool>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </widget>
           </item>
           <item>
            <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
             <property name="orientation">
              <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
             </property>
             <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
              <size>
               <width>1</width>
               <height>20</height>
              </size>
             </property>
            </spacer>
           </item>
           <item>
            <widget class="QWidget" name="cameraAxisWidget" native="true">
             <property name="sizePolicy">
              <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
               <horstretch>0</horstretch>
               <verstretch>0</verstretch>
              </sizepolicy>
             </property>
             <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="cameraAxisLayout">
              <property name="spacing">
               <number>4</number>
              </property>
              <property name="leftMargin">
               <number>0</number>
              </property>
              <property name="topMargin">
               <number>0</number>
              </property>
              <property name="rightMargin">
               <number>0</number>
              </property>
              <property name="bottomMargin">
               <number>0</number>
              </property>
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="cameraXpBtn">
                <property name="toolTip">
                 <string extracomment="X+">Set view direction to +X</string>
                </property>
                <property name="statusTip">
                 <string>Set view direction to +X</string>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string/>
                </property>
                <property name="icon">
                 <iconset resource="../Workspace/MyApp/Resources.qrc">
                  <normaloff>:/icons/pqXplus.png</normaloff>:/icons/pqXplus.png</iconset>
                </property>
                <property name="iconSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>24</width>
                  <height>24</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="flat">
                 <bool>true</bool>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="cameraXmBtn">
                <property name="toolTip">
                 <string extracomment="X-">Set view direction to -X</string>
                </property>
                <property name="statusTip">
                 <string>Set view direction to -X</string>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string/>
                </property>
                <property name="icon">
                 <iconset resource="../Workspace/MyApp/Resources.qrc">
                  <normaloff>:/icons/pqXminus.png</normaloff>:/icons/pqXminus.png</iconset>
                </property>
                <property name="iconSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>24</width>
                  <height>24</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="flat">
                 <bool>true</bool>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="cameraYpBtn">
                <property name="toolTip">
                 <string extracomment="Y+">Set view direction to +Y</string>
                </property>
                <property name="statusTip">
                 <string>Set view direction to +Y</string>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string/>
                </property>
                <property name="icon">
                 <iconset resource="../Workspace/MyApp/Resources.qrc">
                  <normaloff>:/icons/pqYplus.png</normaloff>:/icons/pqYplus.png</iconset>
                </property>
                <property name="iconSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>24</width>
                  <height>24</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="flat">
                 <bool>true</bool>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="cameraYmBtn">
                <property name="toolTip">
                 <string extracomment="Y-">Set view direction to -Y</string>
                </property>
                <property name="statusTip">
                 <string>Set view direction to -Y</string>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string/>
                </property>
                <property name="icon">
                 <iconset resource="../Workspace/MyApp/Resources.qrc">
                  <normaloff>:/icons/pqYminus.png</normaloff>:/icons/pqYminus.png</iconset>
                </property>
                <property name="iconSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>24</width>
                  <height>24</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="flat">
                 <bool>true</bool>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="cameraZpBtn">
                <property name="toolTip">
                 <string extracomment="Z+">Set view direction to +Z</string>
                </property>
                <property name="statusTip">
                 <string>Set view direction to +Z</string>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string/>
                </property>
                <property name="icon">
                 <iconset resource="../Workspace/MyApp/Resources.qrc">
                  <normaloff>:/icons/pqZplus.png</normaloff>:/icons/pqZplus.png</iconset>
                </property>
                <property name="iconSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>24</width>
                  <height>24</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="flat">
                 <bool>true</bool>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
              <item>
               <widget class="QPushButton" name="cameraZmBtn">
                <property name="toolTip">
                 <string extracomment="Z-">Set view direction to -Z</string>
                </property>
                <property name="statusTip">
                 <string>Set view direction to -Z</string>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string/>
                </property>
                <property name="icon">
                 <iconset resource="../Workspace/MyApp/Resources.qrc">
                  <normaloff>:/icons/pqZminus.png</normaloff>:/icons/pqZminus.png</iconset>
                </property>
                <property name="iconSize">
                 <size>
                  <width>24</width>
                  <height>24</height>
                 </size>
                </property>
                <property name="flat">
                 <bool>true</bool>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </widget>
           </item>
          </layout>
         </widget>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <action name="actionRegistration">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Registration</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionI_O">
   <property name="text">
    <string>I/O</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionFusion">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Fusion</string>
   </property>
  </action>
  <action name="actionCustom">
   <property name="text">
    <string>Custom</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="../Workspace/MyApp/Resources.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I set the icons from the Resources.qrc file on various buttons in my user interface using Qt Designer.

I ran this command to create my resources_rc.py file: `pyside2-rcc -o resources_rc.py Resources.qrc`.

When I run `python main.py` to execute my application, none of my icons from my QRC file appear in the user interface.

Is there something else I should be doing to get this to work?  Thanks.

Comment: share MyApp.ui ....

Comment: See edited question.

Comment: Are you sure that .ui is correct? My Qt Designer can't open it plus I can't convert it to .py either with pyside2-uic

Comment: I had to take out some of the text because it wouldn't fit the 30,000 character limit that StackOverflow imposes.  Hang on.  I'm gonna take out unnecessary stuff via the Qt Designer app and repost the file contents.

Comment: So upload it to drive, dropbox or similar service and share the link, incomplete .ui doesn't help.

Comment: I fixed it.  Try it now.

Comment: mmm, I can't reproduce the error. Are you using any IDE?

Comment: mmm, could you share the resources_rc.py to me through drive, dropbox or similar to see where the problem is, in addition to pointing out which version of python and pyside2 you use.

Comment: I am using Python 3.8.2 and Pyside2 5.14.1

Comment: resources_rc.py is at this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xUvo-inX1jCR1d0pKthtqR58jl2eg5nI (had to repost.. uploaded the wrong one)

Comment: How strange to me it works correctly before repost or after repost: See https://imgur.com/a/1Dl1ept .What is the output of `print(QFile(":/icons/pqClip.png").exists())`?

Comment: False.  Really odd.

Comment: Mine looks like this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ddbYUCX9ODivdArn-hkaAP-GpHZ-WY9V

Comment: So the conversion is probably wrong (remove resources_rc.py and all .pyc) and recompile .qrc

Comment: Same issue after removing those files and recompiling the .qrc...  I am using Anaconda with Visual Studio Code and I'm inside an Anaconda virtual environment when I execute main.py, but I don't know how that would cause this problem.

Comment: Test if you have the problem in a python without anaconda (lately I have known of several bugs generated by anaconda when using pyqt and pyside)

Comment: That solved it.  There's a bug with Anaconda, apparently.

Comment: report the bug, also for the next questions indicate your environment: version of python, IDE, pyside2, anaconda, etc.